# Not able to load images from url in a listview using JSON

Tags: android, json, listview

each element in my listview contains a text and an image. i am able to get the text from url using JSON and display in the listview. I am also able to get the url of the images but not able to display them in the list. Here is my code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newslist);
    img_url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iamge_url);
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    new GetContacts().execute();
}

 private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);




                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                  // JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);


                   JSONObject posts = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                   JSONArray attachment = posts.getJSONArray("attachments");
                     for (int j = 0; j< attachment.length(); j++){
                   JSONObject obj = attachment.getJSONObject(j);
                   JSONObject image = obj.getJSONObject("images");

                   JSONObject image_small = image.getJSONObject("tie-small");

                   String  imgurl = image_small.getString("url");  
                    Bitmap picture = getBitmapFromURL(imgurl);

                    HashMap<String, Object> contact = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    contact.put("image_url", imgurl);  //this image i want to load
                    contact.put("icon", picture);      //this displays fine
                    contact.put(TAG_TITLE, title);     // this displays fine
                    contactList.add(contact);
                     }    

               }

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList, R.layout.third_row, 
                new String[] {"image_url",TAG_TITLE,"icon"}, 
new int[] {R.id.iamge_url,R.id.headline3,R.id.imageicon});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and this is my method getBitmapFromURL() for geting images from url:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        Log.e("src",src);
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

There are no errors. The application also does not crash, but in the listview the images are not displayed. i get error in logcat saying:

```
unable to decode stream java.io.filenotfoundexception /android.graphics.bitmap (no such file or directory)
```

i checked the url. it is working. i am able to see the image in my browser using the url. Dont know where is the problem.

Comment: If you just want to show the images, don't break your head over it man, use some library like URLImageViewHelper or UniversalImageLoader. here you just have to pass it the view and url of image you want to load. (you can also give some default drawable as 3rd parameter, for just in case when fetching image fails)

Comment: well.. i hate using libraries as eclipse starts giving java heap errors.. but will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

First get the imageUrl from the JSON and use this method to turn it into a bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(String imageUrl)
{
    if (imageUrl != null && !imageUrl.equals("null"))
    {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue)
        {
            Log.e("Get Thumbnail", "Error retrieving thumbnail");
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException io)
        {
            Log.e("Get Thumbnail", "Error retrieving thumbnail");
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Use this to resize it** (although you can also use the XML attributes of the imageview to scale and resize)

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image)
{
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 175, 175, true);
}
```

And then in the `getView()` of your listview adapter

```
    // Scale and set the Image
    if (myArrayList.get(position).getImage() == null)
    {
    // set default image if there is no image
        imgThumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
    } else {
        imgThumbnail.setImageBitmap(myArrayList.get(position).getImage());
    }
```

Comment: i dont have a getview() method. i an just using a Simple adapter.  how shall i put the images using SimpleAdapter().

Answer (score 0):

You are getting URL from json right...Using that URL you can load ur image...

First Add following permission in AndroidMenifest.xml

```
 <!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     
    <!-- Permission to write to external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then

```
AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity.java
package com.example.imagefromurl;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
 
public class AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         
        // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
        int loader = R.drawable.loader;
         
        // Imageview to show
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
         
        // Image url
        String image_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";
         
        // ImageLoader class instance
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
         
        // whenever you want to load an image from url
        // call DisplayImage function
        // url - image url to load
        // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
        // image - ImageView 
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
    }
}
```

And ImageLoader class..

```
//ImageLoader.java
package com.example.imagefromurl;
 
//import statement
  
public class ImageLoader {
  
    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 
  
    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }
  
    int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
    {
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    }
  
    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }
  
    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);
  
        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;
  
        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }
  
    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
  
            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
  
            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
  
    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }
  
    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }
  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }
  
    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
  
    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }
  
    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
  
}
```

This code can all be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120712203915/http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/).